# Node.js streaming file server with express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a file streaming server with `Node.js` and everything online is telling me to use express.js. Is this the best way to make a file server? When I try to use express and install it, I get this error:

[image]

I have tried to update my npm but that gives me similar errors. I've uninstalled and reinstalled node in it's entirety. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a system configuration issue which is probably off-topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your DNS configuration. Your DNS resolver is not able to resolve `registry.npmjs.org`. You could try temporarily setting `8.8.8.8` (Google DNS) as your DNS server and trying it again.

Comment: Tried that and connection timed out. But now the message is telling me I have proxy and network connectivity problems so I'll pay around with that. Thanks!